# TextFormField moving to HomePage when KeyboardAppears

Tags: flutter, dart

guys.

I'm having some trouble with TextFormFields on my app.

I've got Login screen with Form widget, that works pretty fine, i can put login and password and then do the login.

But after login every TextFormfFeld that i tap to write some words the keyboard appears and then the app crashes and moves back to HomeScreen.

each Form widget has its own Global Key, I don't know why this behavior is occurring.

Things that I've tried:

create a static GlobalKey, but when I do this an error is displayed saying that I'm using a unique global key in too many widgets.

Comment: provide screenshot about errors, and codes

Comment: give more information including your code and the result

Comment: The error is "'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart': Failed assertion: line 2878 pos 14: '_appBarMaxHeight! >= 0.0 && _appBarMaxHeight!.isFinite': is not true."